# How can I refactor this ruby code using the Open/Closed principle or Strategy pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strategy-pattern, open-closed-principle

How can I refactor this ruby code using the Open/Closed principle or Strategy pattern ?
I know that the main thought is 'software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification' but how can I use this in practice?

```
class PaymentService
  def initialize(payment, payment_type)
    @payment = payment
    @payment_type = payment_type
  end

  def process
    result = case payment_type
    when 'first'
      process_first
    when 'second'
      process_second
    end

    payment.save(result)
  end

  def process_first
    'process_first'
  end

  def process_second
    'process_second'
  end
end
```

Comment: “but closed for modification”—not in ruby. One cannot prevent any piece of the code to be modified by 3rd party in ruby.

Comment: I think you mean `result = case @payment_type` in `PaymentService#process`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, instead of passing a `payment_type` you can build an object with a class that processes a payment:

```
class FirstPayment
  def process
    'process_first'
  end
end

class SecondPayment
  def process
    'process_second'
  end
end

class PaymentService
  def initialize(payment, payment_strategy)
    @payment = payment
    @payment_strategy = payment_strategy
  end

  def process
    result = @payment_stategy.process
    payment.save(result)
  end
end

PaymentService.new(payment, FirstPayment.new)
```

As a result, `PaymentService` behaviour can be extended by passing a new strategy (for example, `ThirdPayment`), but the class doesn't need to be modified, if the logic of processing the first or the second payments is changed.